# Is there a way to flag if there's multiple rows equaling eachother in 2 columns?

Tags: google-sheets

Title is kind of confusing but I'm using sheets and I'm trying to get it to flag if there's multiple of 2 columns equaling the same thing. E.g. if A2 = "101" and B2 = "error 3" and then A13 = "101 and B13 = "error 3"

EDIT:
for context, I have a spreadsheet with meeting rooms which have had errors and the errors they have had and what I need to do is go through and find meeting rooms which have had the same errors multiple times and output them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you should add an example input and expected output about how you want to flag.

Comment: Also, remove the tags from the question that is irrelevant. Either Excel or GS.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result